# How to Prevent AG Grid Tooltips from Disappearing in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ag-grid-angular

I'm encountering an issue with AG Grid version 24.1 within my Angular application. The problem arises with tooltips disappearing after approximately 10 seconds, even if the mouse pointer remains stationary. I'm seeking a solution to retain the tooltip component until the mouse pointer moves.

Is there a method or workaround in Angular that allows me to maintain the visibility of AG Grid tooltips until the mouse pointer is moved? I've explored the documentation and various configurations but haven't found a suitable solution yet.

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you include how you are showing those tooltips? Are you just using the title attribute or is it something different?

Comment: @V.S I am using custom tool tip component column['tooltipComponent'] = 'customTooltip';

Comment: You can use the `tooltipHideDelay` to increase the delay. And the docs also mention "Interactive Tooltips will not disappear while being hovered", maybe that's what you can look at.